# Lower bound for two eggs problem

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I have just read about two eggs problem. I know that with decreasing amount of jumps we can reach worst case scenario of first jump $a = \sqrt{2n}$, $n$ is the number of floors, how about the lower bound of the problem?

Let me make it more precise about the issue that I am having.
There are two cases:
1. regular jumps

with regular jumps, let's say it is a jumps per probe

$T(k,n) \leq n/a + T(k-1,a)$ for worst case, where $k$ is number of eggs and $n$ is number of floors

$T(2,n) \leq 2\sqrt{n}$

$T(3,n) \leq 3n^{1/3}$

By induction,
$T(k,n) \leq kn^{1/k}$

How about its lower bound?
 1. gradually smaller jumps

$a +(a-1)+(a-2)+\dots+1 = n$

so $a =\sqrt{2n}$.

So what is the upper and lower bound for this case?

This is where I read about it: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gordon/ysp/egg.pdf

Comment: Did you see the solution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Faster_DP_solution_using_a_different_parametrization?

Comment: On page two, why do they repeat steps 7 and 8?

Comment: I think they made a mistake on that file.

Comment: For wikipedia, it didn't solve for lower bound

Comment: What are you talking about? The Wikipedia article shows the maximum number of floors testable using a certain number of eggs. There is nothing more to say about the problem. If you think there is, then make your question more precise, since at the moment it is meaningless. No problem has a "lower bound"; only (real) numbers do.

Comment: And if you want to notify one other user, put `@username` somewhere in your comment. I only came back here by accident.

Comment: @user21820 

I have made it more precise, please lend me a hand here... thank you very much

Comment: Actually you haven't specified what $T$ is, but I get what you're asking, and as I thought earlier, the Wikipedia article suffices. I've given you an answer but you must read the article if you don't see how to get the recurrence relation. That is the whole point of that section in the article, to show that sometimes it is much easier from a different perspective.

Comment: @user21820 Do you mind explaining it to it a little bit? as i don't quite understand the approach there, thanks a lot

Comment: @user21820 I don't quite get how did it come to the conclusion of O(nk^2) and other subsequent conclusions

Comment: Hmm. Do you know dynamic programming or not? If no, then you need to learn from simpler examples first. If yes, then we're simply solving a different but related problem as I explained in my answer. Ignore the first paragraph in that section, which only concerns the inferior method in the previous section. The first step is to understand the solution to the different problem of finding $f$ as defined by DP. Do you get why $f(t+1,n+1) = f(t,n+1) + f(t,n)$?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to understand the idea in [the Wikipedia article about this very problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Faster_DP_solution_using_a_different_parametrization), which is that it is not good to use the parametrization in your question. Namely, instead of looking for the minimum number of tries needed given $n$ eggs and $k$ floors, you look for the maximum number of floors testable given $n$ eggs and $t$ tries, which follows the trivial recurrence relation. Prove that this is monotonic in $t$, so that you can use any root-finding algorithm to find the minimum $t$ given $n,k$. The article mentions binary search because that's the simplest and you can't do much better than a log factor in practice anyway.

Specifically, following the article by letting $f(t,n)$ be the maximum number of floors testable with $t$ tries and $n$ eggs, you get $f(t,2) = \binom{t}{0} + \binom{t}{1} + \binom{t}{2}$, and it is trivial to invert this function to find the minimum $t > 0$ such that $f(t,2) \ge k$, where $k$ is the number of floors, since it is just a quadratic. Deal with small cases separately where the quadratic is nonzero everywhere. There is no need for upper/lower bounds since the answer is exact. For higher $n$, if you just want an approximation, simply approximate $f(t,n)$ before inverting. For example, one bound is $\binom{t}{3} \le f(t,3) \le \binom{t+3}{3}$, which allows you to find the optimal $t$ to within $3$ of the correct answer if you can invert $x \mapsto \binom{x}{3}$. I leave it up to you to find other more convenient bounds, such as $c(t-a)^3 \le f(t,n) \le c(t+b)^3$ for some constants $a,b,c$, so that inverting is easier.